# How to indicate the source sheet when merging multiple sheets into one

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

There is a lot of tutorials that show how to merge multiple sheets, so basically there is 2 formulas:

```
={FILTER({sheet#1-range},LEN({sheet#1-range-first-column})>0);
FILTER({sheet#2-range},LEN({sheet#2-range-first-column})>0);...}
```

or

`=QUERY({{sheet#1-range};{sheet#2-range};...,"Select * where Col1 is not null")`

Both producing a result sheet but it is not possible to indicate the data provided by a specific sheet. What I want is the result sheet to contain a field that have a name of the source sheet for each row.

Is it possible to achieve by modifying any of the formulas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
=QUERY(
        {{sheet#1-range,index(substitute(sheet#1-range,sheet#1-range,"sheet1"))};
         {sheet#2-range,index(substitute(sheet#2-range,sheet#2-range,"sheet2"))};
         ...,
    "Select * where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: thank you for such a quick answer! any thoughts on this one https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/167035/joining-multiple-sheets-horizontally ?