# Joining multiple sheets horizontally

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a number of spreadsheets

[image]

I want to join them horizontally by Id.

[image]

How would you achieve that?

p.s I should mention that the `id` order could be different in each spreadsheet

Comment: here is an input spreadsheet example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xbte0SS9Xar5o20G89lEhiimY83c6hTHjUCIVAFhSwU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `vlookup()` function in an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276). Put this formula in cell `Sheet1!C1`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    iferror( vlookup(A1:A, Sheet2!A1:C, column(Sheet2!B1:C), false) ), 
    iferror( vlookup(A1:A, Sheet3!A1:B, column(Sheet2!B1), false) ) 
  } 
)
```

If you want a new table in the `Combine` sheet, put this formula in cell `Combine!A1`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    Sheet1!A1:B, 
    iferror( vlookup(Sheet1!A1:A, Sheet2!A1:C, column(Sheet2!B1:C), false) ), 
    iferror( vlookup(Sheet1!A1:A, Sheet3!A1:B, column(Sheet2!B1), false) ) 
  } 
)
```

Comment: is it possible to pick a specific columns?

Comment: Merge all columns in the `Combine` sheet, then use `query()` or `filter()` to create reports in yet another sheet. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: fyi, instead of specifying `column(Sheet2!B1:C)` I used `{2,3}` do define columns that I want.

Comment: Yes... hard coding the column numbers gives the same result as getting the column numbers from the range. Remember to update your hard-coded column numbers if you later insert columns.

Comment: right, however using column() method will update them automatically if they change? right?