# How to pick a custom columns within an array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have next array formula that combines columns from multiple sheets:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    Data1!A2:F, 
    iferror( vlookup(Data1!A2:A, Data2!A2:C, {2,3}, false) ), 
    iferror( vlookup(Data1!A2:A, Data3!A2:E, {4,5}, false) ) 
  } 
)
```

The `Data1!A2:F` returns columns `A:F` from the `Data1` sheet, I want to be able to custom pick columns instead. How can I do that?

Comment: That formula is from [Joining multiple sheets horizontally](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167040/269219). When you copy or closely rephrase content that you did not create into something you post, always insert proper [attribution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:
try to select the colums in this way (now they are ALL selected, delete the columns you do not want)

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    query(Data1!A2:F,"select A,B,C,D,E,F"), 
    iferror( vlookup(Data1!A2:A, Data2!A2:C, {2,3}, false) ), 
    iferror( vlookup(Data1!A2:A, Data3!A2:E, {2}, false) ) 
  } 
)
```

---

Include your formula in a query, like this that keeps values from columns 1 and 4:

```
=query(
  arrayformula( 
  { 
    Data1!A2:F, 
    iferror( vlookup(Data1!A2:A, Data2!A2:C, {2,3}, false) ), 
    iferror( vlookup(Data1!A2:A, Data3!A2:E, {4,5}, false) ) 
  } 
 ),
"select Col1,Col4"
)
```

Comment: I believe it is querying the whole arrayformula result, I want to be able to specify custom columns from the first range `Data1!A2:F,`

Comment: Can you attach a reduced copy of your file?

Comment: here is the one https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FpZKU1WfBjHmV_ouSzH709THttXhhc4sXVsYftBehug/edit?usp=sharing. See the formula within the `Combine` sheet.

Comment: I want to be able to cherry-pick the columns from the `Data1!A2:F` - is the first thing within an arrayformula, when adding `query` and anything like `"select Col1,Col4"` it works a bit differently

Comment: I modified my formula